# Using function parameter value as dictionary key

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

Attempting to build a dictionary using key that comes via function parameter.

```
var progres_mark = function(progress_state) {
  var now = Date();
  console.log({ progress_state : now })
}

progres_mark("encode")
```

Expected

```
{ 'encode': 'Sun Oct 19 2014 18:22:33 GMT+0300 (IDT)' }
```

Actual

```
{ progress_state: 'Sun Oct 19 2014 18:22:33 GMT+0300 (IDT)' }
```

What’s going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the compiler only expects an *identifier* or a *string* and therefore will not evaluate to the variable's value. But you can use bracket notation to achieve what you want.

```
var progres_mark = function(progress_state) {
  var now = Date();
  var obj = {}; obj[progress_state] = now;
  console.log(obj)
}
```

Comment: thank you. SO won’t allow me to accept the question (for another 11min, no idea why this artificial delay is implemented). So once the wait period is expired I will mark it as solved. Thank you.

Comment: glad to have helped :) @MaximVeksler